# Combine every 5 lines

Tags: notepad++, editing

I need to combine every 5 lines into 1. I have a wordlist dictionary which contains 1000 lines example:

```
line 1
line 2
.
line 1000
```

I need to combine every 5 lines:

```
line 1 line 2 line 3 line 4 line 5
.
line 996 line 997 line 998 line 999 line 1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.+)\R(.+)\R(.+)\R(.+)\R`
- Replace with: `$1 $2 $3 $4`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       : beginning of line
(.+)    : group 1, 1 or more any character 
\R      : any kind of line break
        : same pattern occurs 4 times.
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1      : content of group 1
        : a space
        : same for other groups
```